# AWS S3 upload boto status

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I am using Flask and Boto with AWS S3 to upload files. I would like to know the progress so I can show it to the user.

I am `boto.s3client` and

```
s3.put_object(Body=body, Bucket= BUCKET_NAME, Key=key,  ContentType='image/png')
```

For example.

How can I know the progress of uploading?

Comment: Are your objects likely to be large enough to require multi-part uploads?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, whats a general guideline for size?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/uploadobjusingmpu.html